# Android SurfaceView drawing

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am new in android. I reviewed two examples [Custom View with User Interaction](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/05/custom-view-with-user-interaction.html) and [Android SurfaceView](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-surfaceview.html). I want that in second example draw cicle similarly with first example. How I can do this? 
Second question is: when the run() method has to stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution. For correctly work of SurfaceView I had to set background of canvas. When I done it everything is working fine.