# Create a square on the corners of the imageView

Tags: android

I am creating a POC on how to resize an imageView in android. I want to put 4 squares in the corner of the ImageView so I can drag the squares to resize. What should I use to get this result?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the coordinate of the corners
2. Draw rectangles at those coordinates with method like `Canvas.drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)`
3. Get the coordinates of the touch point from onTouch()
4. Resize the imageview with the new size

### Get Coordinates of Touch Point

The class (suppose it is an Activity) should implements OnTouchListener, and register the listener to itself

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    ...
        setOnTouchListener(MyActivity.this);
    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getActionMasked();

        switch(action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Get the coordinates
                int x = (int)event.getRawX();
                int y = (int)event.getRawY();
                // Resize the imageView
                resize();
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

### Resize the ImageView

You can use `ImageView.setMaxHeight()`, `ImageView.setMaxWidth()` to resize the imageview

By the way, does the imageView you want to resize is in fact an image? In that case, using drawable might be a better idea

Comment: Then how can I resize the image?

Comment: Oh my bad, I missed that part. Hold on.

Comment: What is the `Paint paint` all about?

Comment: The class Paint enables you to set the color, transparency, etc of your drawing --http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html

Comment: Do I need to use onDraw method to use the `canvas.drawRect()`?

Comment: You can, it's not necessary

Comment: but how? I am putting up that canvas.drawRect() inside the ACTION_UP. Sorry I am a newbie in android development.

Comment: Create a SurfaceView, do things like draw the rectangles and image on it, then post it to your view  
These links might help:  
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-drawing-circle-at-the-touched-point-of-surfaceview/  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912102/how-to-draw-image-on-surfaceview-android  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139177/android-surfaceview-drawing  
  
Of course, Developer's Guide is always your second best friend  
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an overlay is what you need.
Create a 9-patch drawable with the squares and corners and put that layer on top of your imageview.